# Django template language extends doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi guys I am studying django framework using "django by example" book. The problem I am facing is that the template language does not work even I copy and pasted source code from book and/or github.

A blog application that has post model and is inside the mysite project.
You can see the code in picture and the result too:
Inside blog\templates\blog .

blog\templates\blog\base.html

```
<!-- its base.html -->
     {% load staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}"         rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>My blog</h2>
            <p>This is my blog.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Its the list that extends base.html and located in blog\template\blog\post:

```
 {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
    {% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        <h1>My Blog</h1>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h2>
                <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                    {{ post.title }}
                </a>
        </h2>
        <p class="date">
            Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
         </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
        {% endfor %}
     {% endblock %}
```

Here is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404

from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts=Post.published.all()
    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post=get_list_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                     status='published',
                     publish__year=year,
                     publish__month=month,
                     publish__day=day)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',
              {'post':post})
```

Comment: What is not working? Can you provide more error details or other info?

Comment: Its supposed to show the title of post in but isnt also in detail.html(which i didnt uploade the code) nothing shows

Comment: Can you include your settings for `TEMPLATES`?

Comment: please provide your desired code into views.py file

Comment: I put the code in views.py but nothing changed also settings is correct too.
I also added template loader too but still not working

Comment: Please show your view.

Comment: I put the code in views.py but nothing changed also settings is correct too.
I also added template loader too but still not working

Comment: Ok if you meant views.py

Comment: I don't understand why you won't post your view. We can't help you until you do.

Comment: I added the views.py